# Unity - Subject can move WASD, however WASD doesn't turn where camera points

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm following some guide on character controls and have copied down the following script:

```
#pragma strict

    var walkAcceleration : float = 5;
    var walkDeacceleration : float =5;
    @HideInInspector var walkDeaccelerationVolx : float;
    @HideInInspector var walkDeaccelerationVolz : float;

    var cameraObject : GameObject;
    var maxWalkSpeed : float = 10;
    @HideInInspector var horizontalMovement : Vector2;

    //Jumping Variables
    var jumpVelocity : float = 275;
    var grounded : boolean = false;
    var maxSlope : float = 60;

function Update () {

    horizontalMovement = Vector2(rigidbody.velocity.x, rigidbody.velocity.z);
    if(horizontalMovement.magnitude > maxWalkSpeed){

        horizontalMovement = horizontalMovement.normalized;
        horizontalMovement *= maxWalkSpeed;

    }


    rigidbody.velocity.x = horizontalMovement.x;
    rigidbody.velocity.z = horizontalMovement.y;

    if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0 && Input.GetAxis("Vertical") ==0){
        rigidbody.velocity.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(rigidbody.velocity.x, 0, walkDeaccelerationVolx, walkDeacceleration);
        rigidbody.velocity.z = Mathf.SmoothDamp(rigidbody.velocity.z, 0, walkDeaccelerationVolz, walkDeacceleration);
    }

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, cameraObject.GetComponent(MouseLook).currentYRotation, 0);
    //New movement to remove latency in movement.
    transform.position = Vector3(transform.position.x + Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * walkAcceleration * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y ,
                                 transform.position.z + Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * walkAcceleration * Time.deltaTime);


    //Old movement
    //rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * walkAcceleration, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * walkAcceleration);

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && grounded)
        rigidbody.AddForce(0, jumpVelocity, 0);

}

function OnCollisionStay (collision : Collision){

    for(var contact : ContactPoint in collision.contacts) {

        if(Vector3.Angle(contact.normal, Vector3.up) < maxSlope)
        grounded = true;

    }
}

function OnCollisionExit(){
    grounded = false;
    }
```

The issue is to do with (I'm sure):

> `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, cameraObject.GetComponent(MouseLook).currentYRotation, 0);`

However I'm not entirely sure how to modify this line in order to make it work with my modifications.

Comment: This really doesn't look like Java. Are you sure this isn't `UnityScript`?

Comment: It's in a JavaScript file. It's using Unity parts I guess. Sorry, I don't really know the terminology for it.

Comment: Learning the correct terminology goes a long way in helping people help you

Comment: And now I know. :) It's all part of learning.

Answer (score 0):

you want to rotate the camera, but I dont see setting the rotation anywhere. You just need to take Y Axis (I believe it's Y) from player's rotation and set it to Camera, ie. something like this (idk the syntax of UnityScript so here's C#):

```
Vector3 newRotation = cameraObject.transform.rotation;
newRotation.y = transform.rotation.y;
cameraObject.transform.rotation = newRotation;
```

Comment: `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, cameraObject.GetComponent(MouseLook).currentYRotation, 0);` 

The code above defines where the camera is looking by accessing the MouseLook.js script. Quarternion is used to create rotations and Euler rotates x to x and so on.

Comment: Ok then. I don't see any class declaration or the script name or explanation what is this script attached to so I thought it's related to your character so I thought `transform` refers to player, not to camera.

Comment: The movement script (this one) is attached to a playable capsule. It forward faces where the camera script is facing, which is attached to the camera. The code above moves the rigidbody to the direction of the camera, not the camera itself. My issue is that the rigidbody is turning, however the WASD commands are not. They are entirely static on the axis. Where the camera faces, I'd like to have my subject move forward, not sideways or backwards (depending on where I'm facing)